# emacs edit-server.el doesn't write out it's buffer to web text block

Tags: emacs

Just installed emacs edit-server.el and it's associated Chrome extension.

Install went well.

Only problem I have is I couldn't figure out to "write" the emacs buffer back to web page.  All I saw was web buffer flashing yellow, but no editted text.

I tried various combinations of ^x^m , save etc.

Comment: If you saw the textarea in the browser flash yellow, that *should* mean that the text was just updated.  It sounds like the communication between the two is 'working' otherwise you'd not have seen that, but I can't guess where the bug will be if you didn't wind up with the expected text.  FYI I've experienced issues with it as well, but I don't think I've seen your symptom before.  I've lost my text before though, which *has* caused me to make a habit of using `C-x h M-w` before 'submitting' the text, though, just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: I've also encountered particular web forms which don't work with this extension.  I don't have an exact reason, but I think I'd suspected it was on account of the textareas being generated/displayed by javascript, and maybe not existing in the markup available to the extension.  Just a guess, though.

Comment: I also use Firefox rather than Chrome, so maybe try that, and be sure to test on multiple web sites.

Comment: Well I tried edit-server on another web site and it seemed to work.  In fact I'm typing in emacs right now to fill out this stackoverflow comment text box.

Thanks for you input.